# Можно ли проводить опрос?

Tags: обсуждение, опрос

Ясно, что это неформат для основного сайта.Но можно ли устроить опрос где-либо еще здесь.
Вот например такой:

> Какой вариант вы используете для импорта ткинтера в питоне:
>
> - `from tkinter import *`
> - `import tkinter as tk`
> - Вообще не использую ткинтер.

Comment: Откройте новую комнату в чате. Комментариями привлеките туда заинтересованных участников.

Comment: Я думаю, что это тематично. Просто стоит немного перефразировать вопрос. Например, _"Является ли правильным использование %way_name%, вместо %way_name_2%?"_ или _"Какой способ рекомендуется использовать?"_.

Comment: Кстати, `PEP 8`: _"Absolute imports are recommended"_.

Comment: @nomnoms12 Закроют за невозможность объективного ответа.

Comment: @0xdb https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103535/v-

Comment: Пример уже [обсуждался](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/776848/204271).

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev это совсем другое. Там хоть есть критерии для ответа (скорость). А тут просто опросник.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica да я понимаю, опросники не нужны :)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

А на мой взгляд, это вполне формат для сайта. Хотя кажется, многие могут не согласиться.

Comment: Для формата базы знаний в качестве объективно верного ответа подойдут разве что результаты опроса при наличии репрезентативной выборки, но не сам опрос.

Comment: @andreymal *при наличии предварительно описанных критериев)

Answer (score 4):

**Это оффтопик для основного сайта ruSO и иногда онтопик для Меты.**

В двух словах - цель SO это создание базы прикладных вопросов и объективных ответов:

> Stack Overflow на русском — это сайт вопросов и ответов для профессиональных разработчиков программного обеспечения, энтузиастов программирования и системных администраторов. Сайт создан и управляется сообществом. С вами вместе мы создаём свободную библиотеку подробных ответов на любой прикладной вопрос по программированию и системному администрированию.

Что такое опрос - это удовлетворение любопытства на счет какой-либо темы (кто что любит, яблоки или апельсины, табы или пробелы, xml или json?). Практической пользы от результата - мало. Зная результат, нам, как специалистам, **все равно нужно знать и понимать причины** такого распределения голосов, чтобы сделать свой какой-либо информированный выбор. Узнать сильные и слабые стороны вариантов, чтобы выбрать тот что нам нужен.

Да, иногда, нам может быть нужно оценить объемы использования какой-либо технологии, чтобы выбрать ту, по которой больше специалистов и чаще и лучше дадут ответ. Но это делается не опросом, а изучением статистики.

Также, многие темы опросов, почва для флейма и конфликтов - какая компания лучше, чей движок мощнее, и т.п.

Таким образом, **стоит переформулировать свой вопрос из "опроса" в "вопрос"**. То есть определить что именно вас интересует с прикладной точки зрения, и спросить об этом.

Касательно вашего примера, его не обязательно приводить в виде опроса. Это вполне может быть обычным вопросом "В чем разница/преимущества между А и Б?", и если у вариантов действительно есть различия, то вы о них узнаете.

---

На Мете опросы относительно работы сайта разрешены, если они преследуют не праздное любопытство, а имеют каку-либо практическую цель, т.к. они помогают нам определить консенсус относительно чего-либо (разрешать ли код-ревью, например). Если сообщество решительно настроено по какой-либо теме и это явно не противоречит основным правилам, то второстепенные и негласные правила вполне могут быть изменены или дополнены.